# If a textbox equals two things

Tags: c#, textbox

Is it possible to say that if a textbox equals two things to do something, so something like if textBox1.Text equals "A" or "B" it does something, or would this be accomplished by two if statements? Sample code below.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text == "A" or "B")
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems that you need to learn a bit of C# syntax

Comment: guess I'll have to look into it more then :p

Comment: if(textBox1.Text == "A" || textBox1.Text == "B") ...

Comment: `if(new[]{"A","B"}.Contains(textBox1.Text){}`

Comment: @Swiggs did you ask why?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: probably not the best way to be understood by a beginner

Comment: @NiMa no. Was just thanking you for your help

Comment: @ThomasW.: the question was already answered. I just wanted to show a different perspective. Maybe this is just an example and he actually wants to check many strings. A beginner should learn that a collection is the best way to store many items instead of many variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you should just use an `||` as `or`

```
if (textBox1.Text == "A" || textBox1.Text == "B")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have only one or two values, to check against, create a composite condition using the logical OR operator `||`:

```
if (textBox1.Text == "A" || textBox1.Text == "B") …
```

However this will quickly get cumbersome for more than just a few values. In that case, you might be better off putting all allowable values into a collection, then check if the textbox' text is contained in the collection:

```
var values = new string[] { "A", "B", … };
if (values.Contains(textBox1.Text)) …
```

And although you didn't ask, it might be a good idea to sanitize input; e.g. call `textBox1.Text.Trim()` before you compare values. It's easy for users to accidentally enter too much whitespace.